# When a police officer asks your origin and destination, what are my legal rights?

Tags: united-states, police

I understand [the 10 rules for dealing with the police](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hgjHNIOok0) and that you [dont talk to the police](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wXkI4t7nuc) but if you are stopped by the police and they ask you where you have been and where you are going, how should you reply?

Should your answer vary depending on whether you are being stopped for a minor traffic violation versus being stopped because you fit the identity of someone who fits the description of someone wanted for a misdemeanor or felony?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a politics question, but I can't think of a better place for it either.

Comment: @Bobson - this is offtopic here (despite being a good question). It should go on legal.SE. But we don't have legal.SE :(

Comment: @DVK - With good reason, since everything would have to begin with "IANAL, consult your lawyer"...

Comment: @Bobson - from what I know of lawyers, they would STILL say "IAIL, **consult your lawyer**"

Comment: @user4012 Now we do! Well, not "legal," but "law." I don't know if a migration is worth it at this point, though, considering the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no difference. Your [4th Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) rights or [Miranda rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning) apply here, you may inform the police that you are exercising your [right to remain silent](https://www.aclu.org/drug-law-reform-immigrants-rights-racial-justice/know-your-rights-what-do-if-you) (some states require you identify yourself). Additionally, if they day you are under arrest, you can inform them that you do not answer questions without a lawyer present.

> You have the right to remain silent. If you wish to exercise that right, say so out loud.
>
> You have the right to a lawyer if you are arrested. Ask for one immediately.

Comment: I think the question is more of, what should you tell them to avoid them wishing to arrest you. Doing a Miranda may be your right but may not be the most constructive response to a question at a stop

Comment: @DVK, Ok, 4th Amendment in cases where you aren't under arrest.

Comment: Or is that the 5th against self-incrimination (only applies on the witness stand, maybe?)

Comment: If you aren't under arrest, say nothing and walk away. If you must say something, say "It is my understanding that I am not under arrest. Have a nice day, officer(s)."